# Lead Event Callback Notification

Tags: api, data-synchronization

Is there a general event callback API for salesforce? Essentially I want SFDC to post to my application every time a lead object is created or updated. The alternative is daily jobs to inspect my database en masse, but this is hardly the route I want to go.

Right now I have the 'Professional' edition. Does that limit my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many different options to do that from within salesforce. Some of them include:

- [Triggers](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers.htm) and [@future](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_future.htm) callouts
- [Outbound messages](http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging.htm)
- [Scheduled](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=code_schedule_batch_apex.htm&language=en_US) and [Batch](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) Jobs

Each of the above have pros and cons, it really depends on the sync frequency, amount of data that you need to sync and whether it needs to be real-time or not. Also you need to consider the API limits based on the type and number of licenses that you have.

If you update your question with more specific details around your case, the community will be able to provide more tailored approach and answer to your question.

Comment: As long as your application can process SOAP requests, SFDC's Outbound Notification mechanism seems like the way to go: [http://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_setting_up.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_om_outboundmessaging_setting_up.htm|SkinName=webhelp]

Comment: All of these options are correct, but unfortunately you can't use them with the 'Professional' edition. The solution I ended up with is a one time export of our entire Lead database and a script to import it into my system. Then I scheduled a cron job to use the updated api endpoint to find the daily Leads to inspect one at a time. https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/dome_get_updated.htm